# How to Access $this variable inside nested functions in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, nusoap

I have a controller for Nu soap WSDL Like:

```
    class webservice extends CI_Controller
        {
        function index()
        {
              $this->load->library('encrypt');
              $this->load->model('MWSDl');
//...
            function buy($apicode)
            {
                if(!$this->MWSDl->check_gateway($apicode)) //Error occurred  php Cannot find "$this" Variable
            }
//...
            $this->nusoap_server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        }
    }
```

How to Access `$this` inside `buy` function?
I tried by `global $this` But Error occurred!
Error:
`Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in \controllers\webservice.php on line 9`

Comment: If you want access to `$this`, why have you not made the function a class method? I.e. not defined inside the `index()` method. Also, why are you calling `parent::__construct()` in the method?

Comment: If I put `buy` function out of the index  Nusoap not Working And Too Error Occurred

Comment: Maybe you should tell us about that error. Currently this sounds like an xy problem.

Comment: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in \controllers\webservice.php on line 9

Comment: That makes it sound like you tried to call `webservice::buy(...)` or similar instead of using an instantiated object.

Comment: `buy` Function called by nusoap Class When a client send Request to server

Comment: Try to load model in strtolower like: `$this->load->model('mwsdl');`
[Docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#loading-a-model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going wrong about the whole concept. PHP is not Javascript.You shouldn't nest functions, specially not when using OOP frameworks. If you run function index twice, the second time you will probably get an error that function buy is already declared since first run of index will declare function buy.

I would declare them as class member functions / methods.

```
class Webservice extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct()
        {
             parent::construct();
             $this->load->library('encrypt');
             $this->load->model('MWSDl');
        }

        function index()
        {
            // do something like
            $apicode = 'xxxxxx';
            $this->buy($apicode);

            //or  what ever else you need to do
        }


        function buy($apicode)
        {
            if(!$this->MWSDl->check_gateway($apicode)) {

                $this->nusoap_server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));

            }
        }
    }
```

No need to use globals in codeigniter.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question. I also had the same problem with nusoap. When registering a service you have to make a function. Thus in CI you are creating it inside a class function which makes the service function is nested inside, and cannot be taken outside.

Why don't you try this below? I use it all the time before, with helper etc. It's simple and I have tried it and it works.

Put this inside your nested function: 
$ci =& get_instance();

and the rest you have to replace $this with $ci
eq. $ci->some_model->some_function(); or $ci->some_var = 'something';

And it also work if you tried to call a db.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Use `Phalconphp` OR `Yii` It's Better and faster Way to Web Development:)